# How to use ppoints to generate points within 0 and 0.05 for qq plotting in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, uniform-distribution, qq-plot

I ran [Tassel3](http://www.maizegenetics.net/tassel/) and I filtered results with p-value 
not more than 0.05. This way, it is ok to draw a Manhattan plot. However, for 
a QQ-plot there is a problem.

Say I have 40 thousands SNPs, after filtering, about 1,800 SNPs were 
kept in the output file. Now how do I draw QQ-plot because of partial p-values?

`ppoints` only generate points within (0,1). I think the resulting points 
should be in the filtered range (0,0.05) with the same number (1,800) too. 
`runif` can do the trick, but it is random, each time it generates different 
results. I think this would affect the QQ-plot line.

I figured out three ways to solve it but I am not sure if it is right. 
Hope you guys can give some advices.

the following are three methods:

1. `0.05*ppoint(1800)`
2. `ppoints(1800*100/0.05, a=0.05)`, then I only get the former 1/20  results.
3. `ppoints(40k)`, and use those p-values below 0.05 in plotting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right not to use random points. Version 3 will provide what you want. But as `ppoints(40k)` is just producing 40k equally-spaced values between 0 and 1, it's not too difficult to directly code what you want. To bypass the use of `ppoints()` altogether, use e.g. `(-0.5+1:1800)/40000`; this gives the expected position (under the null) of the 1800 smallest p-values, from a sample of 40000 p-values.

Comment: yes, thank you. a small trick, but a big difference. great! I prefer not using T3 to draw plot for I have more than one hundred traits' results to draw, and I haven't take my time to learn how to use command parameters of T3 to do this batchly. that's why I just use the results of T3 and use R to draw plots batchly.